# Custom marker icon iOS bad quality

Tags: ios, maps, marker

I'm trying to add an image to the marker. How to achieve the best quality? As you can see the Google Map yourself increases it twice.

[image: map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you add an asset to you project or just one image?

So, you need to add asset of images (named like - bigMarker.png, bigMarker@2x.png, bigMarker@3x.png) to your project asset, like on screenshots. That works fine on iOS 9.

[image: Assets.xcassets in project]
[image: bigMarker asset]

And that my sample of code in viewDidLoad:

```
// Add custom position in Kansas
CustomAnnotation *annotation = [CustomAnnotation new];
annotation.title = @"Elevation Burger";
annotation.subtitle = @"The best buns...";
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.0119020f,-98.4842460f);
[self.myMap addAnnotation:annotation];
```

And this one in delegate:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;
    if (annotation != mapView.userLocation) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bigMarker"];
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"burgerBitmap"]];

        UIButton *accessoryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        UIImage *disclosureButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosure"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        [accessoryButton setImage:disclosureButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = accessoryButton;
    }
    return annotationView;
}
```